# R match words in list

Tags: r, list, string-matching

I have a character vector

```
var1 <- c("pine tree", "forest", "fruits", "water")
```

and a list

```
var2 <- list(c("tree", "house", "star"),  c("house", "tree", "dense forest"), c("apple", "orange", "grapes"))
```

I want to match words in var1 with words in var2, and RANK the list elements according to the number of words matched. For example,

```
[[2]]
[1] "house"  "tree"   "dense forest"
```

has 2 matches with var1

```
[[1]]
[1] "tree"  "house" "star"
```

has 1 match with var1

```
[[3]]
[1] "apple"  "orange" "grapes"
```

has 0 match with var1

And the desired output is the following rank:

```
[1] "house"  "tree"   "dense forest"
[2] "tree"  "house" "star"
[3] "apple"  "orange" "grapes"
```

I tried

```
sapply(var1, grep,  var2, ignore.case=T, value=T)
```

without getting the output desired.

How to solve it? A code snippet would be appreciated.
Thanks.

EDIT:

The problem has been edited from single word match to word match in phrases as described above.

Answer (score 4):

you can try

```
var2[[which.max(lapply(var2, function(x) sum(var1 %in% x)))]]
[1] "house"  "tree"   "forest"
```

from the last modification of the OP and @franks comment

```
var2[order(-sapply(var2, function(x) sum(var1 %in% x)))]
[[1]]
[1] "house"  "tree"   "forest"
[[2]]
[1] "tree"  "house" "star" 
[[3]]
[1] "apple"  "orange" "grapes"
```

Comment: The OP changed the desired output, I'd suggest `var2[order(-sapply(var2, function(x) sum(var1 %in% x)))]` Also, in the latest R, there is a `lengths` function, so you could do `lengths(sapply(var2,intersect,var1))`

Comment: thanks @Frank, I did not know I could access elements of lists the same way as in vectors.

Comment: @Frank That is elegant

Comment: @john On this site, it's often better to post a new question rather than to change a question that already has an answer (essentially invalidating the answer). "I'll accept when x" also comes off somewhat badly, I think; most of us are doing this to help and to learn, not for internet points. Anyway, just letting you know; not a big deal.